# "Word Separator for URL Titles" hidden config variable

Tags: config

Is there a hidden config variable for the "Word Separator for URL Titles" setting? What other hidden config variables remain undocumented in the [ExpressionEngine User Guide](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/general/hidden_configuration_variables.html)?

Comment: FYI 'hidden' variables are those that don't have a corresponding setting within the control panel. You can set the Word Separator setting on the Global Channel Preferences page, which is why it's not listed within that section of the user guide.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, there is `$config['word_separator'] = "dash";`

or `$config['word_separator'] = "underscore";`

Answer (score 8):

Devot:ee has a page dedicated to this: http://devot-ee.com/ee-config-vars

Comment: Nice! Looks very comprehensive!

Comment: Very helpful resource.

Answer (score 2):

You can also see any hidden config values that add-ons might have if you turn on the Output Profiler and then on the front end of the site you click Show on "Config Variables" which will show all the config items and their values.

Comment: Good tip! I was unaware of that.

Comment: The only this is that it is not as easy to copy and paste a bunch of different config items if you are wanting to build a robust config file.